# Why am I getting one less space in my c code

Tags: c

For convention let the space key be -
If at the keyboard I enter:

```
J-----a
```

The output is

```
J----a
```

I have traced my program several times with pen and paper and each time I get

```
J'\t'--a
```

Which should be what I entered at the keyboard so why is the output

```
J----a
```

Code:

```
/***************************************************
 *    Replacing spaces with appropriate tabs an      *
 *    spaces to achieve the same effect                     *
 *                                                                                      *
 ***************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAB 4;

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    int printPos=0;
    int chpos=-1;
    int space2tab;

    while( (ch=getchar()) !='@')
    {
                chpos++;
            if(ch!=' ')
            {
                space2tab = TAB- printPos % TAB;    
                while(printPos+space2tab <= chpos)
                {
                    putchar('\t');
                    printPos+=space2tab;
                    space2tab = TAB- printPos % TAB;    
                }
                while(printPos<chpos)
                {
                    putchar(' ');
                    printPos++;
                }
                if(printPos==chpos)
                {
                    putchar(ch);
                    printPos++;
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `TAB` is defined as `4;`, then it becomes `space2tab = 4;- printPos % 4;;`

Comment: Note that your compiler should have been warning you about something like `statement with no effect` on the lines using `TAB`.  Pay heed to your compiler warnings; they're reporting bugs in your code.  If you didn't get such warnings, you weren't compiling with enough warning options enabled.  If you use GCC, consider `gcc -Wall -Werror` — I'd add `-Wextra` and some others too.

Comment: You never set `printpos` back to zero after a newline, and you don't treat newline differently from any other character.  You can get interesting results if you start or end a line with blanks.  You also don't detect EOF — you should add `&& ch != EOF` to the outer loop condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define TAB 4;
```

Defines the token `TAB` as `4;` - **the semicolon is included**. This means that

```
space2tab = TAB- printPos % TAB;
```

is expanded as

```
space2tab = 4; -printPos % 4;;
```

...which is most likely not what you want.

*(`-printPos % 4` is a valid expression which is discarded.*)

---

Define `TAB` as `4` instead:

```
#define TAB 4
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that but I still have the same issue.